# Python "for loop" looping time limit

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

how to set a time limit for "for loop"?

say I would like the looping each 200mms

```
for data in online_database:
    looping time  = 200 mms
    print(data)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Set a variable with the time at before the loop. Inside the loop, check the difference between the current time and the start time. If it's more than 200ms, break out of the loop with a `break` statement.

Comment: The module "time" provides "time" or "time_ns" and "sleep" for this.

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be limited? Is `online_database` an iterator whose `__next__` method could take more than 200 ms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import time

t_sleep = 0.2

for x in range(10):
    print(x)
    time.sleep(t_sleep)
```

this code would sleep for 0.2 secs for every iteration

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help

```
import time

for i in YourSequence:

    current_millis = round(time.monotonic() * 1000)
    max_milis = (current_millis + 200) #200 is for the time difference

    while round(time.monotonic() * 1000) < max_milis:
          #----Your code------
```

Additionally, if your program is large, you could add these lines to periodically keep an eye out if your program has crossed the max time limit

```
if round(time.monotonic() * 1000) > max_milis:
       break
```

Something like this

```
import time

for i in a:

    current_millis = round(time.monotonic() * 1000)
    max_milis = (current_millis  + 200)

    while round(time.monotonic() * 1000) < max_milis:

        #Your Codes......

        if round(time.monotonic() * 1000) > max_milis:
              break

        #Your Codes......

        if round(time.monotonic() * 1000) > max_milis:
             break       

        #Your Codes......
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `default_timer` from the `timeit` module to find how much time has passed:

```
from timeit import default_timer

start_time = default_timer()
looping_time = 0.2

for data in online_database:
    print(data)
    end_time = default_timer()
    if end_time - start_time > looping_time:
         break
```

Note: `default_timer()` returns an amount of seconds from a fixed point in time. It is exclusively used for timing things.

Documentation: [timeit.default_timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.default_timer)